# Insert element into std::vector<void **(void*)>

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I need to insert and retrieve an element from a vector defined as

```
std::vector<void **(void*)> array;
```

The element that I want to push_back is defined as:

```
void *element(void *)
```

Finally, given a `void* data` I want to use the element in the following way:

```
array[i](data);
```

Unfortunately I cannot find the correct way to call array.push_back.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `std::vector<std::function<void*(void*)>>` may have a syntax a little more intuitive than `std::vector<void*(*)(void*)>`

Comment: @Jarod42: It's not equivalent, though.  `std::function` is a lot fancier than a function pointer.

Comment: `using fptr_t = decltype(&element);` would help readability a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a vector of functions returning `void**`, which is impossible.  Functions aren't objects, you can't store them in a vector.

(A function type is legal as a template type parameter, and some template types use these, for example `std::function` and some of the type traits... but `std::vector` requires its parameter to be an object type)

Try

```
std::vector<void* (*)(void*)>
```

to create a vector of function pointers.

Then you just need

```
array.push_back(&element);
```

Comment: That's what I intended to do, thank you! Can you tell me where I can read about difference between void** and void*(*) and in general about pointers with parenthesis?

Comment: @HAL9000: It becomes clearer if you make a declaration with an identifier:  `void* f(void*)` is clearly a function with one parameter; parameter and return type are both `void*`.  Similarly `void** g(void*)` is a function with one parameter, but the return type is now `void**`.  On the other hand `void* (*p)(void*)` is the type of `&f`, a pointer-to-function.

Comment: however array.push_back(&element); gives a compilation error. Ampersand is not needed.

Comment: @HAL9000: I guess your definition of `element` in your real code doesn't match the one in the question?  Using the functions from the above comment, you would do `array.push_back(&f);` or `array.push_back(p);`  The first is straight from a function, the second is from a pointer already.

Comment: Actually the definition is the same. Is an actual parameter of a method.

Comment: @HAL9000: A function parameter can't be a function type either.  It can be a function pointer.